# Images in header not display when included in files of different folders even the path is correct

Tags: html, image

I'm new to programming & this is a simple project. Mainly I have **assets,model,view** folders.my problem is I have a ***header.php*** file with images which is common to all files.so my images are in **img** folder which is inside **assets** folder.So my path to images is

`< img src="assets/img/logo.png ">`

When I include the header in index.php file it works properly.

`require_once('header.php');`

But when I include header into the **user.php** file which is inside **userManagement** folder inside **view** folder even the header is added images are not displaying. Code is
`require_once('../../header.php');`

folder structure is

**assets**

img

```
 logo.png
```

**model**

**view**

userManagement

```
       user.php
```

index.php

header.php

Please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because **index.php** and **user.php** are not in the same directory level. So, when including **header.php** inside **index.php**, the path to the images is `assets/img/`, which is correct. However, when you include **header.php** inside **user.php**, the path to the images is also `assets/img` which is incorrect. If I correctly understand what you've written, then your folder structure looks like this:

```
+ assets
  + img
    - logo.png
+ modal
+ view
  + userManagement
    - user.php
- index.php
```

Hence, you should refer to your images in this way:

```
../../assets/img/
```

You can go around this by adding this line to your **user.php** in the `<head>` section:

```
<base href="../../"/>
```

However, all URLs in **user.php** should be made to point to their targets as if they were two levels down in the main directory.

Comment: I really appreciate your response.when I change path to images as you given,images in *header.php file display properly in files inside folders.but now images are not dispaly in *index.php file since the *header.php & *index.php in same directory level.could you please help me.Thank you

Comment: Did you include it in user.php? From what you describe it looks like you've included it in header.php.

Comment: Yes you right.but when i include it in user.php it doesnt work.how ever could you please explain again.im sorry if i bother you too much.I know this is not a big thing but i need to learn this well.I have 3 images in header.php file.also i need to keep it as a common file & its not in the same directory level of user.php.but its with index.php.if you can please help me.thankyou so much

Comment: In this case you should check for directory levels then set URLs accordingly. Otherwise you can use absolute paths.